# Rails display additional information in dropdown menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have a simple dropdown menu using collection_select in a form:

```
<%= f.label :team %>
<%= f.collection_select(:team_id, Team.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Right now the dropdown menu displays the team name, as it should. I would like the dropdown menu to also display the team :kind (also in the Team database). (ie. "Team name - Team kind")

Any suggestions? The api guide hasn't been too helpful since the team :kind is technically non-essential information in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method like

```
def both_teams
   "#{self.name} - #{self.type}"
end
```

Something like this...

```
collection_select(:team_id, Team.all, :id, :both_teams)
```

Comment: This gives me the following error undefined local variable or method `team' for #<Team:0x007f76c82a34b0>. It seems to be referring to the team in team.name and team.type. Is there not a way to display :name and :kind as an array in the collection_select arguments?

Comment: I believe the method above should be `self.name` and `self.type` since the method is within the `Team` class.

Comment: This answer just copied mine, why is it the one marked as the correct answer?

Comment: @Muhamad Akbar Bin Widayat just edited the answer and copied mine

Comment: @Lymuel I am not try to copied your answer. I just want to fix mrNagoo's answer and the code format. I am sorry for that.

Comment: You should look for the other answers first before updating the above answer, the updated version of the answer is totally the same as my answer dude.

Comment: Lanny suggested the edit and then you magically came up with the same answer two hours later...

Comment: @MrNagoo try to see the time of the update and my answer, my answer is already posted before the above answer is modified

Comment: I'm talking about Lanny Bose on the second comment. He corrected it first. Then you made a new answer, then it got edited. Relax.

Answer (score 2):

Try this
On your model

```
def display_fields
   "#{self.name} - #{self.type}"
end
```

then on your view

```
collection_select(:team_id, Team.all, :id, :display_fields)
```